# Specifying color mapping in react components

Tags: gooddata

Using the new "Colors" section of the analytical designer, I can specify custom colors to use for my insight:

[image]

When I get my visualization object, this comes through with properties that look like this:

```
"colorMapping": [
    {
        "id": "fdda26a33ca048f28bc702f047c04d73",
        "color": {
            "type": "guid",
            "value": "guid3"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "893b13af5d064ec5ba57f82ea3241bbe",
        "color": {
            "type": "guid",
            "value": "guid4"
        }
    }
]
```

Passing that into the `config` section of the react component props results in some console errors (`item.predicate is not a function` in `color.js:219`).  It seems to me that the color map values aren't coming through correctly when I get the visualization object.

Is there any way to get the custom color values and set them in the react component props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Visualization` component consuming URI of existing visualization, it will automatically use this color mapping from visualization object so no extra config is needed. 
If you use explicit components like `BarChart` or so, you need to transform colorMapping into form of so called predicates. For more info please read [Gooddata.UI documentation](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/next/chart_config.html#color-mapping) and provide also colorPallete config. Hope this helps

Comment: The `guid3` and `guid4` turned out to be the code for the colors coming from the project-defined custom palette.  I was able to get that color palette (https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Importing+Custom+Color+Palettes) and specify it in the component (https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/next/chart_config.html#Custom-color-palette) to get the color mapping to work.